# Python multiprocessing: multiprocessing with queue doesn't run faster than single process code

Tags: python, multithreading

I made some multiprocessing examples like below:

```
import time
import multiprocessing as mp
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from multiprocessing import Pool

manager = mp.Manager()
messages_dict = manager.dict()
messages_dict['value'] = ''

def complex_task():
    req = requests.get('https://stackoverflow.com')
    html = req.text
    soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')
    my_titles = soup.select('h3 > a')
    data = []

    for title in my_titles:
        data.append(title.get('href'))

    time.sleep(2)

class abc:
    def all(self):
        complex_task()
        return "This is abc \n what a abc!\n"

class bcd:
    def all(self):
        complex_task()
        return "This is bcd \n what a bcd!\n"

class cde:
    def all(self):
        complex_task()
        return "This is cde \n what a cde!\n"

class ijk:
    def all(self):
        complex_task()
        return "This is ijk \n what a ijk!\n"


def crawler(sites, ps_queue):
    for site in sites:
        ps_queue.put(site)

def message_collector(ps_queue):
    while True:
        site = ps_queue.get()
        messages_dict['value'] += site.all()
        ps_queue.task_done()


def main():
    site_list = [abc(), bcd(), cde(), ijk()]

    #
    # Single process
    #
    # start_time = time.time()
    # messages = ''
    # for site in site_list:
    #     messages += site.all()
    # print(messages)


    #
    # Multi process
    #
    ps_queue = mp.JoinableQueue()
    message_collector_proc = mp.Process(
        target=message_collector,
        args=(ps_queue, )
    )
    message_collector_proc.daemon = True

    start_time = time.time()

    message_collector_proc.start()
    crawler(site_list, ps_queue)
    ps_queue.join()

    print(messages_dict['value'])


    print(time.time() - start_time)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

but it turned out that single process and multi process program showed same runtime speed. As you can see above the codes, there are two parts of code in `main()`: `Multi process` and `Single process`.

Runtime on Macbook pro late 2013(OS X Sierra): 
- Single Process : 16.92385721206665
- Multi Process : 16.362822771072388

Almost same...

I have no idea why this happened... Need your helps!

Comment: Local performance cannot be evaluated in applications with external links.

Comment: It's looks like this is multi process in the sense that it spawns a single subprocess that runs `message_collector`, that sequentially crawls each site. Presumably what you actually want is for each different site to be crawled by a different subprocess, with those running in parallel?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers

Comment: @TomDalton Yes! But if I have to use `Pool` and my code just spawns a single subprocess that runs `message_collector`, why the multi-process API I used is included in the `multiprocessing` library? As I know of, there is a library called `subprocess`.....

Comment: The subprocess you are currently spawning does run in parallel with your main script (the parent process). However, your parent process / script just sits around, doing nothing while it waits for the child process to finish (the `ps_queue.join()` line. You could potentially have the parent process doing other useful work during that time, which would mean you had 2 processes doing useful work in parallel.

Comment: @TomDalton Why should parent process do useful work? All spawned processes do `crawling` and accumulate messages and parent process wait until all children processes are done. Can not understand why this make code slower...

Comment: I was answering your question "why the multi-process API I used included in the `multiprocessing` library". E.g. I was explaining a use case for spawning a single child process. "All spawned processes do `crawling`". That's true but as I said, in your case you spawn 1 child process, that crawls all the sites sequentially while the parent process waits for it to finish. That's why it's the same speed as the single process version - you essentially haven't parallelised anything.